# Viewing local storage contents on IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, local-storage

How can I view the contents of HTML5 local storage in IE? Chrome and FireFox provide a way through their developer tools to view the contents of local storage but I couldn't find that information using IE9 developer tool.

Comment: Have the same problem but none of the solutions below worked. I can see localStorage, even the length but not the values stored

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Since localStorage is a global object, you can add a watch in the dev tools. Just enter the dev tools, goto "watch", click on "Click to add..." and type in "localStorage".

Comment: Is there a way to manipulate the storage without issuing commands through the console? ie. localStorage.removeItem

Comment: Well... as long as you have a console, you can always see and interact with the localStorage.. but the native dev tools you have on Chrome or Firefox to fiddle with the local storage are way more easy and informative (..and sadly this is still true on IE11, AFAIK..)

Answer (score 77):

In IE11, you can see local storage in console on dev tools:

1. Show dev tools (press <kbd>F12</kbd>)
2. Click "Console" or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>
3. Type `localStorage` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Also, if you need to clear the localStorage, type `localStorage.clear()` on console.

Comment: If you need to add anything to localstorage: localStorage.setItem(newItem, 'hello'); for removing: localStorage.removeItem(newItem);

Answer (score 13):

Edge (as opposed to IE11) has a better UI for Local storage / Session storage and cookies:

- Open Dev tools (F12)
- Go to Debugger tab
- Click the folder icon to show a list of resources - opens in a separate tab

[image: Dev tools screenshot]

Comment: FYI my IE 11, after clicking the folder, shows the loaded scripts, but NOT the following sub-folders: Local Storage, Session Storage, etc., as illustrated in the image above.

Comment: @PeteAlvin I didn't see it in IE 11 on Win 8, but did see it on Win 10

Comment: Same here.  Don't see the storage folders in IE11 on Win 8.1.

Comment: Same here. Don't see the storage folder in IE11 in Win7

Comment: Windows 10, IE 11 - no Local (or session) storage folder.

Comment: @ the above... this answer is talking about Edge, not IE11.