# How to view the Localstorage into IExplorer 10?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, local-storage

I can see Localstorage into Chrome for example, but while using ie10 or ie9, there is no way to figure out how the Localstorage look like.

Is there some tools or ie addons to install so that i can view the localstorage while using IE?

PS: I'm working into Windows 8

Comment: check this answer here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539877/viewing-local-storage-contents-on-ie][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539877/viewing-local-storage-contents-on-ie

Comment: well im into windows 8... and i cant see it!

Comment: which ie version do u have

Comment: I have the ie10 one!!

Comment: press F12 - go to "Console" tab and enter `localStorage` - voila. Or like stated in the linked answer - "Script" Tab -> observe -> localStorage.

Comment: Nice one... Hey can u add this as an Answer?

Comment: Thats what i told ya . see in dev tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your developer tools with <kbd>F12</kbd> or by going to the Settings menu -> devtools.

Either go to the "Console" tab and enter `localStorage` or

Add it on the watchlist: "Script" tab -> observe -> enter `localStorage`. You need hit the refresh button to see newly added values.