# View localStorage in Internet Explorer - Cannot get name/value pairs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, internet-explorer, local-storage

All,

I realize the question of how to view localStorage in Internet Explorer has been answered several times.  That's not my question.

[Viewing local storage contents on IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539877/viewing-local-storage-contents-on-ie)

[How to view the Localstorage into IExplorer 10? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16688370/how-to-view-the-localstorage-into-iexplorer-10)

I did:

1. Open IE Developer Tools (F12)
2. Go to Console
3. type in localStorage

This shows me that there is an object called localStorage that is known to IE.  **However, I cannot get the name/value pairs like I can from Chrome.**

It gives me a way to walk the JavaScript object for localStorage, but I tried expanding all the nodes and can't find my name/value pairs (see screen capture).

[image: IE Developer Tools localStorage]

I am trying to view what a specific Plunk is putting into localStorage, the demo for ngStorage.

[ngStorage Demo Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/3vfRkvG7R9DgQxtWbGHz?p=preview)

Here's what I see in Chrome:

[image: Chrome Developer Tools localStorage]

**How can I get `ngStorage-x` and `ngStorage-y` from Internet Explorer?**

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `localStorage` to look at the data in the console in `IE` does work.

What is happening in the example you posted is that the code is being ran on another domain.

`LocalStorage` is sandboxed in a specific domain, including subdomains.

The demo code runs in `run.plnkr.co` while the page you are viewing is `plnkr.co`

Therefore `ngStorage-x` and `ngStorage-y` is not in the dataset inside IE because you are viewing for `plnkr.co`.

Chrome offers a `resources` tab like what you are viewing to inspect other pages, but the chrome console itself would not have access to that pages `LocalStorage`.

You can manually go to `run.plnkr.co` in IE, and type `localStorage` in the console, and you will see `ngStorage-x` and `ngStorage-y` values. (After you executed the code in the demo).

Comment: Thank you, I did know that localStorage is sandboxed to the domain/subdomain.  What I did not realize was that IE Developer Tools only shows localStorage for the current sandboxed domain/subdomain point of reference, unlike Chrome resources where I could see everything.

Comment: Right. But if you use Chrome's console and type in `localStorage`, you will see similar results to what IE reported in its console. Since the console is for the whatever domain that the address bar has.

Comment: Would you happen to know of anything for IE similar to Chrome's Resources tab?  I'm seeing differences in behavior with ngStorage in IE and Chrome, and that would really help.

Comment: I'm not sure. I haven't used IE dev tools very much myself. If they don't have anything natively, there might be a plugin available.